# Default list model and generics JAVA

Tags: java, swing, generics, defaultlistmodel

When I looked at the API specification default list model it stated the class uses generic. When I went to create an instance of the class, it didn't need it or permit it. How are generics integrated with DefaultListModel, and how can it be used?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never *need* to use generics because it's simply a compile time check (see [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) for more details).

Essentially, once your code is compiled, generic type information is stripped away, so it's never necessary for your code to run correctly. Generics simply provide a way for the compiler to perform static checks to make sure that you are using types in a consistent/safe manner.

Comment: I knew that going in, but if I choose to use generics why doesn't it let me?

Comment: I solved the issue, I'm using se 6 and in se 6 it's not generic :-(

Comment: I assumed it was generic as of se 6 as well

Comment: You can't assign a generic type to an instance of a class unless the class definition requires one. There would be no benefit to allowing you to do so since the only benefit is type checking and that benefit comes from the return values and method arguments of the class's functions taking arguments of the generic type.